# Small-Signal Modelling of Buck Control

Tags: buck, control

[image]

[image]

**In equation 3.7, why is the author using v_in and not v_in(s)?**

Comment: Could it be because he assumes Vin is DC, and therefore a constant?

Comment: He uses capital V_in for DC, not v_in (as shown in 3.8)

Answer (score 4):

What the author describes in this equation is the *control-to-output* transfer function of the voltage-mode-controlled buck converter operated in continuous conduction mode or CCM. In a buck converter, the equivalent schematic reveals the input voltage source \$V_{in}\$ multiplied by the ac-modulated duty ratio as shown in the below picture:

[image]

This is an excerpt from my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1949267512) on transfer functions that I recently released. From the given expression, you can see the presence of a leading term, \$H_0\$ and it contains the dc input voltage and other ohmic contributors such as the inductor equivalent series resistance: \$H_0=\frac{V_{in}}{V_p}\frac{R_{load}}{R_{load}+r_
L}\$. In this expression, \$V_{in}\$ represents de dc input voltage while \$V_p\$ designates the modulator sawtooth peak voltage. Considering the term \$V_{in}\$ directly affecting the small-signal duty ratio, you can have an idea how poor the input voltage rejection of the CCM buck operated in voltage mode is. A feedforward term can easily cure this.